# RD-gateway like solution without implementation MS RDGW role

Tags: reverse-proxy, remote-desktop, rdp

Looking for a solution to connect to various Windows hosts based on port number.
I want to be able to choose which machine to connect to without needing to implement Microsoft's RDGW role.

It may sound a little petty, but the only reason I need this is to be able to use mstsc.exe without needing to configure the advanced tab with the rdgw settings on mstsc.exe.

Alternatively, if I could programmatically create an rdp file with the rdgw settings/credentials would also work - I couldn't find a way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the contents of a .rdp file. change what you want and save as .rdp
as noted full address:s: HOST PC and gatewayhostname:s: RDP GATEWAY

screen mode id:i:2
desktopwidth:i:1400
desktopheight:i:1050
session bpp:i:16
winposstr:s:0,3,161,151,969,778
full address:s:host.company.com
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:0
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
displayconnectionbar:i:1
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:0
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
disable wallpaper:i:1
disable full window drag:i:1
allow desktop composition:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
gatewayhostname:s:rdpgateway.company.com
gatewayusagemethod:i:2
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:1
promptcredentialonce:i:1
drivestoredirect:s:
use multimon:i:0
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:

Comment: Is there a way to specify the user/pass for the gw?